# C#->C++ Dispatch DATE rounding in OleAutomation when it shouldn't?

Tags: c#, c++, datetime, com, ole

## Background

Am I doing something wrong with MFC/OLE?

According to the documentation COleDateTime has a milisecond resolution.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1z81fxe(v=vs.80).aspx

Yet a C# DateTime of 08:38:42 and 501 milliseconds, passed to my very basic MFC/COM/OLE function of date type DATE (VT_DATE) is rounded up to 08:38:43 before I get the chance to use it.

It worries me that for the obvious case of 23:59:59.501, it will cascade the date to the next day.

For my case I want to search in a database, and passing any `System.DateTime` which contained milliseconds will sometimes skip to the next second or even the next day!

Are there other types other than VT_DATE in the .cpp file and DATE in the ODL file that preserve the resolution?

**ODL**

```
[id(1)] void FindEntriesFromDate(DATE dateFrom);
```

**CPP DISPMAP**

```
DISP_FUNCTION(CMyClass, "FindEntriesFromDate", FindEntriesFromDate,VT_EMPTY,VTS_DATE)
```

**CPP Prototype**

```
void FindEntriesFromDate(DATE dateFrom);
```

## Here's the proof.

I construct C# datetime objects, and pass them to a bare-bones traditional C++ MFC OLE/COM project with a DATE parameter in the ODL/CPP/H files.

**Round down**

```
System.DateTime(2013, 7, 12, 8, 38, 42, 499);
C++ dateFrom = 41467.360214108798
C++ OleDateTime(dateFrom).Format() results in 12/07/2013 08:38:42
C++ COleDateTime(dateFrom).GetSeconds() results in 42
```

**Round up**

```
System.DateTime(2013, 7, 12, 8, 38, 42, 500)
C++ dateFrom = 41467.360214120374
C++ OleDateTime(dateFrom).Format() results in 12/07/2013 08:38:43
C++ COleDateTime(dateFrom).GetSeconds() results in 43
```

**Complete day rollover:**

```
System.DateTime(2013, 7, 12, 23, 59,59, 501)
C++ dateFrom = 41467.999994224534
C++ OleDateTime(dateFrom).Format() results in 13/07/2013
C++ COleDateTime(dateFrom).GetSeconds() results in 0
```

Comment: `DATE` type (`VT_DATE` variant) is an alias for `DOUBLE` and the value is in days. The precision/resolution is limited on its own and rounding is possible. If you are sensitive to rounding, you perhaps would want to prefer integer types in seconds, milliseconds or smaller units, e.g. `FILETIME` style 64-bit integer in 100 ns units.

Comment: I just discovered this, which isn't the answer to what I should do, but validates that it's probably not my fault.

To extract the information, the GetSeconds() operator eventually uses `::VariantTimeToSystemTime()'

This article indicates that there's a fundamental problem with it http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17576/SystemTime-to-VariantTime-with-Milliseconds

Supported by http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297463/en-gb

Comment: This is just an automatic consequence of a wrapper not having a GetMilliSecond() method.  Which is fair, the clock isn't that accurate.  Seconds are the smallest unit, they therefore get rounded.  Truncating would just make more programmers unhappy.  You'll have to spin your own, you could get the fractional amount by converting back to double and subtracting.